# Auth::check() is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am using laravel5 and I want to return and API response after checking user is logged in or not.

But it seems Auth::check() is not working.

Comment: Please share some code and\or add move info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using token based authentication.

If you are using popular jwt-auth token based authentication, then you should use below code.

```
 $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include use Auth; on top of the controller?
Also it's boolean so you should use it like

```
if(Auth::check()){
 //user logged in
}else{
//user not logged in;
}
```

Also you can include Auth middleware to the controller so functions are only accessible to logged in user.

Comment: What happens when you use Auth::user(); 
I mean, does:
$user = Auth::user();
gives you $user == null;

What is the error that you get in response.

Comment: I am using jwt-auth thats why after login, laravel default method was not working, jwt authenticate function is working for me now.